# Calling javaScript in UIWebview in ios

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uiwebview

Hi want to load the java script in uiWebview and below the code  i want to load in UIWebview

```
<a class="twitter-timeline" href="https://twitter.com/twitterscreenname" data-widget-id="id">Tweets by @screenname</a>
 <script>!function(d,s,id){var js,fjs=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],p=/^http:/.test(d.location)?'http':'https';if(!d.getElementById(id)){js=d.createElement(s);js.id=id;js.src=p+"://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js";fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js,fjs);}}(document,"script","twitter-wjs");</script>
```

Thankyou

Comment: have tried something ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use:

```
[webview loadHTMLString:htmlString baseURL:nil];
```